# Is there a valid C++11 program with the expression 'C++11'?

Tags: c++, c++11

The name of the programming language C++ derives from the parent language C and the ++ operator (it should arguably be ++C) and, hence, the expression `C++` may naturally occur in C++ programs. I was wondering whether you can write a valid C++ program using the 2011 standard (*without extensions*) and containing the expression `C++11` *not within quotes and after pre-processing* (note: edited the requirement, see also answer).

Obviously, if you could write a C++ program prior to the 2011 standard with the expressions `C++98` or `C++03`, then the answer is a trivial yes. But I don't think that was possible (though I don't really know). So, can it be done with the new armory of C++11?

Comment: Can it be part of an expression? For example, `"C++11";`.

Comment: @sftrabbit within a string would be trivial, so no.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I cannot think about any template or overloading tricks to make that possible. You cannot change the meaning of `11`, neither will it be parsed as `C + (+11)`. You're just missing an additional operator, `C+++11` should work fine (and might even do more justice to all those major improvements than a mere standard qualification, but Ok in this case it should be `C++++11`, which has the same problem again ;)). (But then again I'm not that much of a super-magician so maybe someone can do it or at least *prove* it impossible.)

Comment: Written alone, C++ grammar would *always* parse `C++11` as `((C)++)11)` *(ordering, not literal parenthesis)*.  And given any symbol `x`, `x11` doesn't seem to be parseable.

Comment: The token `++` will always be parsed as the increment operator token, leaving you with the stray `11` (note that `C+++11` works). I'd be really impressed if someone could get around this (being on quite a low level of the compilation process) without the use of macros ...

Comment: I'm not even sure how to do it with macros. Just `#define`ing `C` to empty won't work, since you cannot `++` literals. Neither can you `#define ++ +` or similar (or can you, man that would be really evil?). Other than that, what about `// C++11`, no strings, no macros? ;)

Comment: Hm, I'm not convinced this question is off topic. It's specific, it's unique to the programming profession, it's answerable, and although not visibly practical, it's a "fun" question whose answer may contain interesting or insightful information about syntax. At least, I've seen other "fun" questions that haven't been closed as being off topic.

Comment: Too bad it isn't called `C+=2`.

Comment: @dan04 that would be a different language altogether.

Comment: Would `C++//` be close enough?

Comment: `c + + 11`  is valid (as is `c+ +11` of course)

Comment: @acheong87 Yeah, it's a welcome change from the usual *"How make jQuery draw a OpenGL from C++, help please!"* questions.

Comment: If macros were allowed this would be easy:
#define C (newline)
C++11[(char*)0];

Comment: In addition to Christian's `// C++11`, there's also `#if 0` / `C++11` / `#endif`, which uses no strings nor macros. Depending on your definition of macro trickery, `#define EMPTY()` / `int C = 0; C+EMPTY()+11;` may or may not qualify: it is not trickery in the `#define C` sense (which would work, as Aaron's comment shows), but it is another sense of macro trickery. The preprocessed result contains `C++11` (try stringizing if you think it would be `C+ +11`), as `C` `+` `+` `11` tokens rather than `C` `++` `11`.

Comment: `#include <C++11.hpp>` is not a string actually (h-char-sequence).

Comment: Close attempt: defina a `class X` that overloads both unary and binary +. Then use `X C;` and `X x[] = { X() /* 10 more times */ };` and write `C++11[x]` to get the compile error that post-increment `operator++(int)` has not been defined for class X. I.e. `++` is never parsed as two seperate + tokens.

Comment: @DyP you don't need a `.hpp` in the filename so you can make it look even better: `#include <C++11>`

Comment: `_C++11[""];` has implementation-defined behaviour and can be correct if `_C` is a macro for `return` or `throw`.

Comment: @MarkRansom: `import C++1y.modules; // if only...`

Comment: This comment thread ably demonstrates why this question does not belong here. Try writing it on your blog, instead!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**NO** if we require the characters `C++11` to be *outside any literal, after preprocessing* -- because at translation phase 7 the three tokens will be `identifier`, `++` and `integer-literal`

The first two tokens are a `postfix-expression`, the later is a `primary`.

There is no reduction in the grammar that can contain these two nonterminals in sequence, so any program containing `C++11` will fail syntax analysis.

*However*, if you do not consider character literals to be strings, then the answer is **YES** as you can contain it in a wide character literal:

```
int main()
{
    wchar_t x = L'C++11';
}
```

which does not use the preprocessor or a string literal, and the construct is required to be supported by the standard:

> The value of a wide-character literal containing multiple c-chars is implementation-defined.

Comment: hmmm. the answer has changed since I accepted it. I don't like that (you could have written another one). The trem "string" in my question is ambiguous: it could be narrowly interpreted as `std::string`, but I would regard anything within quotes (single or double) as "string".

Comment: rather than unaccepting your answer, I edited it. I hope that's okay for you. thanks for you effort!

Comment: It is wildly inappropriate to edit someones answer to completely change the semantic content, especially when you don't know the difference between a character literal and a string literal.

Comment: sorry, no harm intended. I object, though, to your *completely change the semantic content* -- I don't think I did that, so my edit was not *wildly inappropriate*, I merely tried to adapt the answer to remain an acceptable one.

Comment: The reasoning doesn't take into account that `n++11` for example can occur inside a valid program (if n belongs to `return`).

Comment: @ipc: No keywords end in `C`, so `C` must end an identifier or a user-defined literal.  Similarly `11` must start a `ppnumber`, so it must be an integer, floating, user-defined integer, user-defined floating literal.  All of which are primaries.

Answer (score 0):

> So, can it be done with the new armory of C++11?

No.

Comment: hmm. I could just believe you, but I rather accept and answer that comes with some good arguments.

Comment: @Walter: I can't prove a negative to you, unless you want me to quote the entire C++11 standard. All the "good arguments" in other answers apply to previous C++ standards too, and are therefore not part of answering your question "has this changed in C++11?"

Answer (score 0):

Define “valid C++ program”.

The C++ standard defines a “well-formed C++ program” as “a C++ program constructed according to the syntax rules, diagnosable semantic rules, and the One Definition Rule”. This leaves open the possibility of C++ programs that are not well-formed. (C explicitly has the notion of programs that are conforming but not strictly conforming, e.g., that use extensions of a particular compiler.)

If you consider it valid to use extensions, then you can implement a C++ compiler that permits `C++11` in some context.

Comment: +1 for the idea. But extensions are, obviously, not allowed. They alter the language. With extensions *almost anything* can be rendered valid.